# Для кого мы отвечаем на вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение

Вопросы задают разные люди (по возрасту и образованию, по уровню владения языком и т.д.). Но как мы должны отвечать на них? Здесь возможны **три крайних варианта**, и нужно по возможности выбрать оптимальное решение.

1) **Отвечаем только автору вопроса,** работаем только для него, учитывая его возможности.Он понял ответ, и это значит, что результат достигнут.

2) **Отвечаем для всех,** то есть обязательно даем общее решение, а потом переходим к частному вопросу (или наоборот).  Это принцип составления "энциклопедии русского языка". Ведь на сайт заходят и другие люди, они читают наши ответы и надеются найти нужную информацию.

3) **Надо сначала четко ответить на конкретный вопрос автора,** чтобы ответ был ему понятен, **учитывая его его уровень знаний.** Но потом **нужно дать обобщенное пояснение,** полезное для всех и понятное всем. (Это деление ответа на части должно прослеживаться, если это необходимо).

Это не праздный вопрос, я уже сталкивалась **с таким мнением, что отвечаем только автору вопроса.** Мне кажется, что это неправильно.

Это же не личное общение и не личный заказ, это общественная аудитория, и **интересы общества должны быть не на последнем месте.**

**А как вы думаете, для кого отвечаете вы?**

Comment: Надо соблюдать золотую середину. И стараться не писать "трактаты", которые нужны прежде всего самому ответчику: они поднимают его самооценку.

Comment: Библейская притча. Дай человеку рыбу, и он будет сыт один день, научи его ловить рыбу, и он будет сыт всегда. Вот и здесь также. Коротко ответить - значит решить  задачу. Дать ключ к пониманию проблемы - значит научить  решать подобные задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Прежде всего отвечаем, конечно, автору. Но отвечая автору, мы отвечаем и другим пользователем, которые, возможно, интересуются этим или аналогичным вопросом.

Но мне непонятен в вашем вопросе пункт 2. Что значит "даем общее решение, а потом переходим к частному вопросу (или наоборот)"?

Наша главная задача  - дать правильный ответ. А наш ответ( хотим мы того или нет) становится общедоступным. И тем самым может оказаться полезным другим.

Comment: Серж,   здесь просматриваются две позиции. Некоторые участники считают, что интересы автора превыше всего. Если это, к примеру,  школьник, то нужен один ответ (можно и «на пальцах» объяснить, лишь бы ему понятно было), если  более подготовленный человек, то и ответ должен быть соответствующим. Мне такая позиция кажется неверной. Школьнику надо подобрать простой ответ, но затем добавить сведения, интересные и полезные для других, в том числе для участников форума, для их уровня.

Comment: А то часто в открытую говорится: а зачем здесь  анализ, зачем обобщение? Человек меня понял, и ладно.   А мы не только этому человеку отвечаем (это мое мнение).

Comment: @Sharon, с одной стороны,  вы правы. Но с другой, часто бывает трудно понять, насколько подготовлен автор вопроса к дополнительным сведеньям.  Поэтому в некоторых случаях углубляться не стоит. Речь, конечно, не идет о постоянных участниках форума.

Comment: Серж, углубляться надо только при необходимости. Мне самой не нравятся ответы, когда начинают пересказывать всё, что связано с темой, вместо того чтобы дать четкий ответ. Мы не  учебник и не учебные сайты, но мы должны ссылаться на официальные материалы (ПАС, Розенталь). Собственно говоря, мой вопрос непосредственно связан с темой обособления  обстоятельства времени в начале предложения. Сразу несколько ответов показались мне неубедительными, в том числе указание в комментариях на то, что работаем для автора, а ему вроде бы понятно.

Comment: Но насколько я помню, все ваши ответы касательно этой темы были предельно четки. Ничего лишнего. А спорить может кто угодно. А как отвечать - это уже ваше личное дело.

Comment: К сожалению, Серж, никак не могу с Вами согласиться. Вот, например,  показательный ответ, за который проголосовал форум https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449803/Выделяется-ли-тут-знаком-препинания . Я думаю, что обоснование здесь предельно нечеткое. Ну и о личном деле. Конечно, это личное дело каждого в пределах требований к ответам. Но я и вопрос задаю, чтобы обсудить проблему, а не навязывать свою точку зрения другим.

Comment: Sharon, ну вот видите, порой детальное объяснение на нашем форуме не проходит.

Comment: А как я это я должна увидеть? По голосованию? Мне не хочется критиковать данный ответ (участник только начал отвечать), хотя объяснение там совершенно некорректное. Тема не имеет отношения к деепричастиям, нет понятия "обычное обстоятельство", нельзя отвечать методом исключения (эта тема имеет свое обоснование). Но вот посетители, которые зайдут на сайт, о чем узнают из этого ответа? Что существуют обычные обстоятельства?  Что обособления нет, потому что это не деепричастие?

Comment: Sharon, да, именно по голосованию.

Comment: Про голосование я уже всё рассказала, оно не в пользу нашего сайта и не прибавит ему доверия и уважения. Так  на вопросы не отвечают.

Comment: Ну с этим ничего нельзя сделать.